# $order->collectTotals()->save(); wanted to show query

Tags: magento

At some place in my code I am executing "$order->collectTotals()->save();" and I am trying to for example echo just below it but it is not echoing. So all I wanted to convey is somewhere control is not coming back. So my point is how can I see which query is getting executed when save function get called.Please help.

Comment: You won't be able to se only that exact one, but you can turn on query logging in `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and try to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Try out `$order->printLogQuery(true);` this will print collection query.

This will work for your